# Wait for two observables finish with zip

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

This is the method code. I'm trying to wait for two observables to complete using zip, but nothing logs, not even the http calls in fooProvider are called.

```
let obsArray: Observable<any>[] = [];

this.idArray.forEach(id => {
  obsArray.push(this.fooProvider.bar(id, 1));
});

Observable.zip(obsArray)
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: If you need to wait until all Observables complete you should use `forkJoin` instead. Otherwise try unpacking the array with `Observable.zip(...obsArray)`.

Comment: @martin will unpacking work? I thought `zip` emitted a value when all observables emitted a value. So not only when all are completed. Would `forkjoin` be the only solution?

Comment: It worked with forkJoin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Observable.zip` takes arguments `(a, b, ..., n)`. I wasn't able to make it work with an array directly, but it should work with `apply`:

```
const zip = Observable.zip
zip.apply(null, obsArray).subscribe(...)
```

`apply` will convert the given array into a function call with the array elements passed as arguments.

EDIT: As per @martin's comment, you can also use the spread operator if your environment supports it. `zip(...obsArray).subscribe(...)`